# Find element text using xpath in selenium-python NOt Working

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

[html looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeWw5.png)I have written this code to scrape all courses from a url. For this I am trying to get the count of courses using `xpath`. But it does not give me anything. Where I am doing wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait`
```

`class FinalProject:`

```
    def __init__(self,url= "https://www.class-central.com/subject/data-science"):`
        self.url = url
        base_url = 'https://www.class-central.com'
        self.error_flag = False
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(<path to chromedriver>)
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        sleep(2)
        self.count_course_and_scroll()

    def count_course_and_scroll(self):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30);
        ele = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Not right now, thanks.')));
        ele.click()
        print "----------------------POP UP CLOSED---------------------"
        total_courses = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='number-of-courses']")
        print total_courses
        print total_courses.text
        self.driver.close()
```

`fp = FinalProject()`

Comment: Please share the html codes that you work on.

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: @Jose I have shared a screenshot of the html. I dont know how should I share the complete one.

Comment: @Guy No errors `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="af387306f394aab0b195eb03399f4a0c", element="0.13137647096001892-2")>` is the output for `total_courses` and `total_courses.text` gives blank string.

Comment: @python_user, you should share your code as text, but not as image. Also edit your code as there are some indentation issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `text` doesn't work you can try `get_attribute`

```
print total_courses.get_attribute('text')
#or
print total_courses.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: `print total_courses.get_attribute('innerHTML')` gave me the result but `print total_courses.get_attribute('text')` gave NOne as output. Why is it so? and why `text` is not working?

Comment: @python_user maybe you can extract the parent text `total_courses = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[span[@id='number-of-courses']]")` `print total_courses.text`. It will give you `187 courses available`

Answer (score 0):

```
ele = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Not right now, thanks.')));
ele.click()
print "----------------------POP UP CLOSED---------------------"
total_courses = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='number-of-courses']")
```

In that piece of code, I suspicious 2 things:

1. Does the popup always appear?
2. Does the text of `number-of-courses`show in time?

If you are not sure about 1., I would recommend to put it in a try catch

And about 2. - wait until some text appears on that element

```
try:
    ele = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Not right now, thanks.')));
    ele.click()
finally:
    total_courses = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='number-of-courses' and text() != '']")
    print total_courses.text
```

Comment: `Try`/`catch`?... are you sure? :) This is definitely not a `Python` code. https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: Thank you, I'm obviously not familiar with python. But the idea is still the same.